# Understanding and Implementing Thinning Algorithm in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to implement my own Thinning Algorithm in Matlab to understand the thinning algorithm. I am following http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/morphology/node2.html and implementing my own code, but the result is incorrect.

Here is my code:

```
%for the sake of simplicity, the outermost pixels are ignored.
for x = 2:1:511
    for y = 2:1:511

        % if this pixel is not black, then, proceed in.
        if (frame2(y,x) > 0)                

            % the pos(1 to 8) here are for the surrounding pixels.
            pos(1) = frame2(y-1,x-1);
            pos(2) = frame2(y, x-1);
            pos(3) = frame2(y+1, x+1);
            pos(4) = frame2(y+1, x);
            pos(5) = frame2(y+1, x-1);
            pos(6) = frame2(y, x-1);
            pos(7) = frame2(y-1, x-1);
            pos(8) = frame2(y-1, x);

            nonZeroNeighbor = 0;
            transitSequence = 0;
            change = 0;

            for n = 1:1:8
                % for N(P1)
                if (pos(n) >= 1)
                    nonZeroNeighbor = nonZeroNeighbor + 1;
                end

                % for S(P1)
                if (n > 1)
                    if (pos(n) ~= change)
                        change = pos(n);
                        transitSequence = transitSequence + 1;
                    end
                else
                    change = pos(n);
                end

            end

            % also for S(P1)
            if ((nonZeroNeighbor > 1 && nonZeroNeighbor < 7) || transitSequence >= 2)
                markMatrix(y,x) = 1;
                fprintf(1, '(%d,%d) nonzero: %d transit: %d\n', y,x, nonZeroNeighbor, transitSequence);
            else %this else here is for the reverse.

            end

        end
    end
end


    for x = 2:1:511
        for y = 2:1:511
            if (markMatrix(y,x) > 0)
                frame2(y,x) = 0;
            end
        end
    end

    savePath = [path header number2 '.bmp']; 

    imwrite(frame2, savePath, 'bmp'); %output image here, replacing the original
```

From the site above, it states the function S(P1) as:

> "S(P1): number of 0 to 1 (or 1 to 0) transitions in the sequence (P2, P3, ..., P9)"

For this part, my codes are below "% for S(P1)" and "% also for S(P1)" comments.  **Am I implementing this function correctly? The output image I got is simply blank. Nothing at all.**

For the correct output, I am aware that there is a logical problem. Regarding the site, it states:

> When part of the shape is only 2-pixel wide, all pixels are boundary points and will be marked and then deleted.

This problem is to be ignored for now.

Comment: Pass 1 rule states: *Mark any edge pixel P1=1 **not** satisfying at least one condition*. I think `transitSequence` should be < 2 in that case, in order to mark the center pixel. Also, a sequence `0-1-0` or `1-0-1` is to be interpreted as a single transit sequence and you are counting those twice (both `0->1` and `1->0`). Simplest way would be to set `change` to P(8) before the loop (`change=pos(8)`) and then divide `transitSequence` by 2 after the loop.

Comment: I think you are right about change=pos(8) part, and it seems I also forgot a "not" operator in the if statement there, so now, I got: if ~((nonZeroNeighbor <= 1 || nonZeroNeighbor >= 7) || transitSequence < 2)  And now it seems to work ok. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm... strange, after I make the algorithm loop until no change is made, somehow, I don't see any thinning edges. I see only points. I have a feeling that I am still missing something...

Comment: Did you write your condition like in your previous comment? Because it still seems wrong to me (one condition is inverted, the other one isn't). I think it should be: `~((nonZeroNeighbor <= 1 || nonZeroNeighbor >= 7) || transitSequence >= 2)`.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested. This time, the algorithm seems to not even do anything to the image. 

I start to wonder whether the algorithm from the site is reliable or not...

Comment: But the site states that *When part of the shape is only 2-pixel wide, all pixels are boundary points and will be marked and then deleted*, and then describes a "Modified Algorithm" below. I believe that's the one you should go for.

Comment: While your statement is true, at least, I want to test from the most primitive step. I mean, shouldn't I have at least some thinned lines to look at and not just points? :o

Comment: You stated that you "loop until no change is made". If I got that right, this means that sooner or later you will get to a 2-pixel wide line, which will be cleared in next step, right?

Comment: The thing is I have tested with 1-10 pixel wide lines and sadly, the result is all the lines became dots one way or another. I was expecting 1-pixel wide line to stay intact, but no, all the lines became dots. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a go at the problem and think I managed to get the algorithm to work. I've made several small edits along the way (please see the code below for details), but also found two fundamental problems with your initial implementation.

Firstly, you assumed all would be done in the first pass of step 1 and 2, but really you need to let the algorithm work away at the image for some time. This is typical for iterative morphological steps 'eating' away at the image. This is the reason for the added while loop.

Secondly, your way of calculating S() was wrong; it counted both steps from 0 to 1 and 1 to 0, counting twice when it shouldn't and it didn't take care of the symmetry around P(2) and P(9).

My code:

```
%Preliminary setups
close all; clear all;
set(0,'DefaultFigureWindowStyle','Docked')

%Read image
frame2 = imread('q1.jpg');

%Code for spesific images
%frame2(:,200:end) = [];
%frame2 = rgb2gray(frame2);

%Make binary
frame2(frame2 < 128) = 1;
frame2(frame2 >= 128) = 0;

%Get sizes and set up mark
[Yn Xn] = size(frame2);
markMatrix = zeros(Yn,Xn);

%First visualization
figure();imagesc(frame2);colormap(gray)
%%

%While loop control
cc = 0; 
changed = 1;
while changed && cc < 50;

    changed = 0;
    cc = cc + 1;
    markMatrix = zeros(Yn,Xn);

    for x = 2:1:Xn-1
        for y = 2:1:Yn-1

            % if this pixel is not black, then, proceed in.
            if (frame2(y,x) > 0)                

                % the pos(2 to 9) here are for the surrounding pixels.
                pos(1) = frame2(y,   x);
                pos(2) = frame2(y-1, x);
                pos(3) = frame2(y-1, x+1);
                pos(4) = frame2(y,   x+1);
                pos(5) = frame2(y+1, x+1);
                pos(6) = frame2(y+1, x);
                pos(7) = frame2(y+1, x-1);
                pos(8) = frame2(y,   x-1);
                pos(9) = frame2(y-1, x-1);

                nonZeroNeighbor = 0;
                transitSequence = 0;
                change = pos(9);

                for n = 2:1:9

                    %N()
                    nonZeroNeighbor = sum(pos(2:end));

                    %S()
                    if (double(pos(n)) - double(change)) < 0
                        transitSequence = transitSequence + 1;
                    end
                    change = pos(n);

                end

                %Test if pixel is to be removed
                if ~( nonZeroNeighbor == 0 || nonZeroNeighbor == 1 ...
                    ||nonZeroNeighbor == 7 || nonZeroNeighbor == 8 ...
                    ||transitSequence >= 2)

                        markMatrix(y,x) = 1;
                        fprintf(1, '(%d,%d) nonzero: %d transit: %d\n', ...
                            y,x, nonZeroNeighbor, transitSequence);
                end

            end
        end
    end

    %Mask out all pixels found to be deleted
    frame2(markMatrix > 0) = 0;

    %Check if anything has changed
    if sum(markMatrix(:)) > 0;changed = 1;end

end

%Final visualization
figure();imagesc(frame2);colormap(gray)
```

[image: Lines before algorithm is run]

[image: Lines after algorithm is run]

Comment: Note, the lines in the final image are not really as disconnected as they seem - it mostly comes from MATLAB not displaying all the '1's.